# ObjectDeletedException: deleted entity passed to persist

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two entities like the below:
Device:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "device")
private Set<DeviceLine> deviceLines;
```

DeviceLine:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "device_uid")
private Device device;
```

DeviceComponent Manager.Class:

---

```
DeviceLinePersistenceManager dlpm = new DeviceLinePersistenceManager();
try {
    dpm = new DevicePersistenceManager();
    Set<DeviceLine> set = new HashSet<DeviceLine>();
    for (LineStatus lineStatus : list) {
    Device deviceRetrieval = dpm.findDeviceByIp(lineStatus
                        .getDeviceIp());
    if (deviceRetrieval != null) {
    Set<DeviceLine> set1 = deviceRetrieval.getDeviceLines();
    if (!set1.isEmpty()) {
    Iterator<DeviceLine> iterator = set1.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        DeviceLine line = iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
        DeviceLine lineToDeleted = dlpm.find(line.getUid());
        dlpm.purge(lineToDeleted.getUid());
    }
    }
    dpm.update(deviceRetrieval);
    }
}
```

when the run the above code iam getting the ObjectDeletedException: deleted entity passed to persist.
    i am unable to delete the deviceline entries. The exception is thrown when `dlpm.purge(..)` is called,help me out.

Comment: and what does the purge method look like?

Comment: @BOZHO, the purge method looks like the below...                    public void purge(D entityToPurge) throws EntityPurgationException {if (entityToPurge==null) { throw new EntityPurgationException( "Entity cannot be purged. Entity can not be found."); }        else { EntityTransaction jta = getEntityManager().getTransaction(); jta.begin(); getEntityManager().remove(entityToPurge); jta.commit(); } }

Answer (score 0):

Try `dlpm.purge(lineToDeleted);`. Currently you are passing the Uid, rather than the entity itself.